# why is react returning parsing error: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, parsing

Failed to compile
I'm trying to run a currency converter app but i keep getting this when i try to fetch the response from an API

./src/Components/currencyconvert.js

```
  Line 25:22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  23 |              const currencyAr =  ["EUR"]
  24 |              for (const key in response.data.rates){
> 25 |                  currencyAr.push.(key);
     |                                  ^
  26 |               }
  27 |          this.setstate({currency: currencyAr });
  28 |          })
```

Comment: you want to remove that dot so it should be `currencyAr.push(key);` as push is a function

Answer (score 1):

Simple remove the dot.

```js
currencyAr.push.(key);
```

should be

```js
currencyAr.push(key);
```